# Blocks reappearing after breaking

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing MC 1.9, in singleplayer without commands. When I break blocks they keep reappearing despite the break animation. My frame rate was low but the problem was still there after I fixed the frame rate. I have tried fixing the frame rate multiple times with no success in fixing the initial problem.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, what is called "block lag" is from the game taxing the hardware being used (your computer in this case) for more RAM.
Normally, Minecraft can get away with a fairly small 2 gigabytes of RAM, but with larger modpacks, it's common to increase the assigned RAM limits to 4GB or more.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to framerate. This is related to latency and memory issues. I have the same issue when playing myself with a large modpack like Resonant Rise or a resource pack. Note that the blocks usually eventually do disappear, but you might have to mine them again.

The problem could be related to a lack of memory in Java. You could try and assign more memory. However, I'm not sure if this fixes it.